# How to Use/Import CSVParser

Tags: java, apache, csv

I am looking to use the Apache CSVParser. However, I'm stuck on even how to use it. Am I meant to import it? Or download a particular file?

Here is the link for reference: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#method.detail

Comment: You always have to download the Jar file to be able to use a Java class.  (Maven will do this for you, so check the artifact ID if you're using that.)

Comment: Here's the download link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi